# How to create dynamic TableView footer by changing height of cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, footer

I want to create a footer which is dynamic to the height of the tableview cells.

My initial situation looks like:

[image]

If I click on a row, it change the height of this cell to 194 (44 before)

[image]

It don't show all rows.

If I get the footer -150 it looks like:

[image]

And if I close all cells it looks like and the 150 which I get to footer with -150 are white here:

[image]

My code:

```
var selectedCellIndexPath: Int?
let selectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 194.0
let unselectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 44.0
var cellsHeight = [44, 44, 44]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    if selectedCellIndexPath != nil && selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath.row {
        selectedCellIndexPath = nil
    }
    else {
        selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath.row
    }
    if selectedCellIndexPath != nil {
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
    }
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let rowHeight:CGFloat = 44
    var rowsHeight:CGFloat = 3 * rowHeight
    /*for i in 0..<cellsHeight.count {
        rowsHeight += CGFloat(cellsHeight[i])
    }*/
    let topHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height
    let viewHeight = self.view.frame.height
    let headerHeight:CGFloat = 30
    let height = viewHeight - topHeight - rowsHeight - headerHeight //- 150

    return CGFloat(height)
}
```

Only one row will have the height 194 and the other 44. Any ideas how to solve the problem?
Thx

Edit:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    //dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "workoutDateCell", for: indexPath) as! WorkoutDateTableViewCell
        cell.typeLabel.text = "Beginn"
        cell.dateDatepicker.date = Date()
        cell.dateDatepicker.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: cell.dateDatepicker.date)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "workoutDateCell", for: indexPath) as! WorkoutDateTableViewCell
        cell.typeLabel.text = "Ende"
        cell.dateDatepicker.date = Date()
        cell.dateDatepicker.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: cell.dateDatepicker.date)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "workoutSportsCell", for: indexPath) as! WorkoutSportsTableViewCell
        cell.sportsLabel.text = "Sportart"
        cell.sportstypeLabel.text = workoutSports[coreData.getSportsIndex()]
        cell.sportsPicker.delegate = self
        cell.sportsPicker.dataSource = self
        cell.sportsPicker.selectRow(coreData.getSportsIndex(), inComponent: 0, animated: false)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath.row {
        return selectedCellHeight
    }
    return unselectedCellHeight
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To archive this you can use only cells instead of footer view.

**Step 1:** Remove Footer View.

**Step 2:** Add Cell of Date Picker.

**Step 3:** When you click on Begin & End DateTime cell, then insert DateTime cell below selected cell and reload table view.

**Step 4:** Hope that will resolve your problem.

Let me know if you have any query.

**Edit:** As per discuss you only need to remove the extra cell separator by using tableFooterViewForSection.

So you only need to add below line to solve your problem:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:tableView.frame.width, heigth:0))
```

And Remove `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat` method.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: If I understand this right, I should create 3 extra cells for the pickers and show one below the cell I clicked?

Comment: No. Are you using static or dynamic cell prototype?

Comment: Dynamic cell prototype

Comment: Ok, then you only need to create one cell for DateTime Picker. And when you click on any cell then rearrange cells by changing the place of picker object in the array and reload the table view.

Comment: Is this the same like change the height of the clicked cell? I don't know what you mean in detail..

Comment: can you add all delegate methods which you implemented for the table view? Then I will show you how you can manage by cell it self.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144720/discussion-between-minumaster-and-mmbach).

Comment: Thanks for your help :)